# How can I close an Android popup window programmatically?

Tags: android, popup

I want to forward calls in a simple way, just by clicking a button.

Forwarding the call is done by dialing a GSM service code. However, after doing this, a popup window appears that tells if the action was successful or not.

Is there any way to suppress or close this popup window programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about [USSD codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) used by GSM/UMTS than no, there's no way to suppress or close the confirmation popup.

The API was requested in the ticket below, but remains unresolved:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for those who come to this question meaning a self-started popup window. Make a class member variable for the popup window.

```
PopupWindow popupWindow;
```

Assuming it was initialized and shown previously, it can be closed as necessary with

```
if (popupWindow != null) {
    popupWindow.dismiss();
}
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898723/dismiss-the-popup-window-by-back-button) for more.