# dismiss the popup window by back button

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I want to Dismiss the popup window by clicking outside of the popup window or by the back button, but when click on the back button my application exit's, instead of exiting the application I want to close the popup window.

here is my code,

```
ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);  
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 0,14);
        popupView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu);

        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);

        TextView tvpopupwork = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupwork);
        TextView tvpopupabout = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupabout);
        TextView tvpopupservices = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupservices);
        TextView tvpopupcontact = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupcontact);

        Typeface typeFace2 =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arboriaboldregular.ttf");
        tvpopupwork.setTypeface(typeFace2);
        tvpopupabout.setTypeface(typeFace2);
        tvpopupservices.setTypeface(typeFace2);
        tvpopupcontact.setTypeface(typeFace2);

        tvpopupwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Ourwork.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        tvpopupabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Aboutus.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });

        tvpopupservices.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Services.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        tvpopupcontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Contact.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Its gives me the result what I want but when I closes the menu the it does not opens again, I want to open it again so what should I do?
thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Replace

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

with this

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: I had to set the background to a non null drawable, at least `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: Also, to listen it's state use `setOnDismissListener`

Answer (score 7):

Maintain global reference for `PopUpWindow` and override `onBackPressed()`...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

To dismiss by the same `Button`...

```
    ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing()) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                popupWindow = null;
            } else {
                // show pop up now
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any solution to close the popup window by the same button?

Comment: @akky777 That was caused by onBackPressed event was captured by the hosting activity not the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way: Implement `onBackPressed()` and add

```
if(popup!=null) {
    popup.dismiss();
    popup=null;
}
```

And set your `PopWindow` with below:

```
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: @akky777 You will get ACTION_OUTSIDE when the touch is outside the activity. but this is only for my requirement

Answer (score 2):

please write `onBackPressed(`) and have following code

```
if(popup!=null){
   //dismiss the popup
   popup.dismiss();
   //make popup null again
   popup=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed() callback in your code and check to see if your pop-up is already showing(then dismiss it), else you call super to get normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `PopupWindow popupWindow` as Global variable

use `popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (popupWindow != null) {
        if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably safer to use `if (popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing())`