# android:handle back button on base adapter class

Tags: android

How to handle back button on base adapter class.
In my application,created two popup windows on a Base Adapter class.
I want to close this popup window one by one while click on back button.

Comment: means you don't want to close them by dialog/popup cancel button

Comment: yes  I want to close the popup window on back button click.

Comment: Here I use a popup window,not a dialog.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898723/dismiss-the-popup-window-by-back-button     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256221/dismiss-pop-up-window-when-back-button-is-pressed

Comment: I already tried this one but didn't help me.